# Is this code setup safe as a captcha?

Tags: html, captcha

I'm thinking this code isn't safe as a captcha, but could the experts please let me know if my assumptions are correct? Basically, as you'll see, the captcha number is listed right there in the code, and it looks to me like a bot can get the value and fill in the captcha.

I say this not only because of the way it looks but because this auto registration bot keeps on getting me.

Here's the code:

```
<img src="/system/writer.php?R=0&amp;T=681554" alt="Code" />
<div style="clear:both;"></div>
<input type="hidden" name="syscode" value="681554" />
<strong>Enter Code:</strong>
<input name="code" type="text" id="code" />
```

Am I right that this captcha is basically a joke?

Comment: Yes, you are right. The captcha should be stored on the server, not like this.

Comment: This is not a captcha at all, bots will easily get this number. But a programmer setting up the bot may die from laughs, so maybe this captcha will work.

Comment: Conversely, it would be a good way to spoof the bot providing that hidden input if it were not the actual value.

Comment: It is easily defeated by a bot... but only those that know about it. The majority of bots don't.

Comment: does the captcha image contains the same value 681554??

Comment: @TravisJ Thats a bit optimistic. Anyone going to the trouble to break the captcha in the first place will notice that. I'm assuming the hidden field is there so the captcha verification can be done on the client side, so you'd be spoofing yourself anyway.

Comment: @Joel - That is correct. I had not assumed that the bots would be hard coded for the exact scenario, but if that is the case then the author would have no trouble distinguishing the difference.

Comment: @WaleedKhan Good point. There is a little value in just having a unique captcha implementation, even if it is extremely weak.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### What is captcha?

> A CAPTCHA (pron.: /ˈkæp.tʃə/) is a type of challenge-response test
>   used in computing as an attempt to ensure that the response is
>   generated by a human being. The process usually involves a computer
>   asking a user to complete a simple test which the computer is able to
>   grade.

### About your implementation

Your captcha code has to be stored on server and NOT on the client side. If the secret code comes on the client side (what you did, even is a hidden HTML element) isn't good. It's not secured.

You have to generate an image that will come on the client as `captcha.png` for example (not containing the code).

But, if you want to be faster and more secured I recommend you to use [Google reCaptcha](http://www.google.com/recaptcha).

### Google reCaptcha

- It's Free! Yep, reCAPTCHA is free.
- It's Useful. Why waste the effort of your users? reCAPTCHA helps to digitize books.
- It's Accessible. reCAPTCHA has an audio test that allows blind people to freely navigate your site.
- It's Secure. Most other CAPTCHA implementations can be easily broken.
- It's Popular. Over 200,000 sites use reCAPTCHA, including household names like Facebook, Ticketmaster, Twitter and Craigslist.
- It's Easy. reCAPTCHA is a Web service. As such, adopting it is as simple as adding a few lines of code on your site. For many applications and programming languages such as Wordpress and PHP we also have easy-to-install plugins available. We generate and check the distorted images, so you don't need to run costly image generation programs.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it's a joke. Any bot trying to deceive the Captcha will be able to read the value of the hidden field.

Comment: I cannot believe this! I mean, it's been on the site for years and touted as a captcha - I mean why else use one but just recently I really looked at it and wow, it's garbage. The site is powered by PHPIzabi. It's had TONS of security/spamming issues that I've resolved but resolving this is going to be hard because it uses TPL files and so I can't even install a real captcha...

Thanks everyone for your comments - awesome help!